# Change icon weather in SP WEATHER module

Tags: php

I have installed the weather module SP weather but I woul like to change the weather icons with someone created by me and installed into a folder of the root of my website: example: mywebsite/images/weathericons

The native file of "SP wether module" that control the icons is the helper.php but I am not able to change and let it works with my icons.

Here is the file:

```
<?php
/*------------------------------------------------------------------------
# mod_sp_weather - Weather Module by JoomShaper.com
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
# author    JoomShaper http://www.joomshaper.com
# Copyright (C) 2010 - 2014 JoomShaper.com. All Rights Reserved.
# @license - http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html GNU/GPL
# Websites: http://www.joomshaper.com
-------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

// no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

class modSPWeatherHelper
{    
    private $data = array();
    private $forecast = array();
    private $woeid;
    private $location;
    private $params;
    private $moduleID;
    private $moduledir;
    private $nightIDs = array(27,29,31,33);
    private $iconURL = 'http://l.yimg.com/os/mit/media/m/weather/images/icons/l/%d%s-100567.png';




    /**
    * Init Class Params
    * 
    * @param object $params
    * @param int $id
    */
    public function __construct($params, $id)
    {
        jimport('joomla.filesystem.file');
        jimport('joomla.filesystem.folder');
        $this->params    = $params;
        $this->moduleID  = $id;
        $this->moduledir = basename(dirname(__FILE__));
        $this->getWoeId();
        $this->data      = $this->_getWeatherData();
        $this->forecast  = $this->_getForecastData();
    }


    /**
    * Error Container array
    * 
    * @var array
    */
    private $errors = array();

    /**
    * Get Errors, If index is null errors stored as numeric array.
    * 
    * @param int | string $index    default is NULL
    * @return mixed
    */
    public function error($index=null)
    {
        if( !empty($this->errors) )
        {
            if( is_null($index) ) return  $this->errors; 
            else
            {
                if( is_null($this->errors[$index]) ) return false;
                else return  $this->errors[$index]; 
            } 
        } 
        else return false;
    }


    /**
    * Set errors in error variable. If index is null errors stored as numeric array.
    * 
    * @param mixed $msg
    * @param mixed $index     default is null. 
    */
    public function setError($msg, $index=null)
    {
        if( is_null($index) ) $this->errors[] = $msg;
        else $this->errors[$index] = $msg;

    }

    /**
    * PHP CURL function
    * 
    * @param string $url
    * @param array $query   default is array
    * @return string
    */
    private function getCurl($url, $query=array())
    {
        $requestURL =  $url;

        if( !empty($query) and is_array($query) ) $requestURL .= '?'. http_build_query($query,'','&');

        if (function_exists('curl_init'))
        {
            // initializing connection
            $curl = curl_init();
            // saves us before putting directly results of request
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
            // url to get
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $requestURL );
            // timeout in seconds
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
            // set useragent
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
            if( strtolower(substr( $requestURL , 0, 5))==='https' )
            {
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
            }
            // execute curl
            $data = curl_exec($curl);
            // closing connection
            $error = trim(curl_error($curl)); 
            curl_close($curl);
            if( !empty($error) ) $this->setError('"'.$error.'" in module "'.$this->moduledir.'"');
            return $data;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->setError('cURL extension is not available on your server.  in module "'.$this->moduledir.'"');
        }
    }


    /**
    * Simple caching function
    * @version  1.3
    * @param string $file
    * @param string | array $datafn                  e.g:  functionname |  array( object, function) ,
    * @param array  $datafnarg    default is array  e.g:   array( arg1, arg2, ...) ,       
    * @param mixed $time         default is 900  = 15 min
    * @param mixed $onerror      string function or array(object, method )
    * @return string
    */
    private function Cache( $file,  $datafn, $datafnarg=array(), $time=900, $onerror='')
    {

        if (is_writable(JPATH_CACHE))
        {
            // check cache dir or create cache dir
            if (!JFolder::exists(JPATH_CACHE.'/'.$this->moduledir))
            {

                JFolder::create(JPATH_CACHE.'/'.$this->moduledir.'/'); 
            }

            $cache_file = JPATH_CACHE.'/'.$this->moduledir.'/'.$this->moduleID.'-'.$file;

            // check cache file, if not then write cache file
            if ( !JFile::exists($cache_file) )
            {

                $data =  call_user_func_array($datafn, $datafnarg);
                JFile::write($cache_file, $data);
            }  
            // if cache file expires, then write cache
            elseif ( filesize($cache_file) == 0 || ((filemtime($cache_file) + (int) $time ) < time()) )
            {
                $data =  call_user_func_array($datafn, $datafnarg);
                JFile::write($cache_file, $data);
            }
            // read cache file
            $data =  JFile::read($cache_file);
            $params['file'] = $cache_file;
            $params['data'] = $data;
            if( !empty($onerror) ) call_user_func($onerror, $params);
            return $data;
        } else {
            return   call_user_func_array($datafn, $datafnarg);
        }
    }


    private function onDataError($params)
    {
        $data = json_decode($params['data'],true);

        if( isset($data['code']) and $data['code']==500 )
        {
            JFile::Delete($params['file']); 
            $this->setError('Cannot retrive data in module  "'. $this->moduledir.'".');
        } 

    }


    private function onForecastError($params)
    {
        $data = json_decode($params['data'],true);
        if( empty($data['query']['results']['item']['forecast']) )
        {
            JFile::Delete($params['file']); 
            $this->setError('Cannot retrive forecast data in module  "'. $this->moduledir.'".');
        } 

    }


    private function onWoeIdError($params)
    {
        $data = json_decode($params['data'],true);
        if( is_null( $data['query']['results'] ) ){
            JFile::Delete($params['file']); 
            $this->setError( 'Cannot get "'.$this->params->get('location').'" woeid in module "'. $this->moduledir.'".' ); 
        }
    }

    private function onLocationError($params)
    {
        $data = json_decode($params['data'],true);
        if( is_null( $data['query']['results'] ) ){
            JFile::Delete($params['file']); 
            $this->setError( 'Cannot get "'.$this->params->get('location').'" location id in module "'. $this->moduledir.'".' );
        }

    }

    private function makeYQL($query, $param=array('format'=>'json'))
    {
        $url   = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=';
        $url2   = rawurlencode($query);
        $url   .= str_replace('%2A','*', $url2 );
        $url   .= '&'.http_build_query($param,'','&');


        return $url;
    }



    /**
    * Get Location woe ID
    * 
    */
    private function getWoeId()
    {
        $query = "select woeid from geo.places(1) where text='".$this->params->get('location')."'";
        $URL = $this->makeYQL($query);


        if( $this->params->get('useCache')==='1' )
        {
            $data = $this->Cache(
                'woeid.json',
                array($this,'getCurl'),
                array($URL),
                (60*60*60),
                array($this,'onWoeIdError')
                );
        } else {
            $data = $this->getCurl($URL);
        }

        $data = json_decode($data,true);

        $this->woeid = $data['query']['results']['place']['woeid'];
    }


    /**
    * Get place Location 
    * 
    */
    private function getLocation()
    {
        $query = 'select id from xml where url="http://xoap.weather.com/search/search?where='.$this->params->get('location').'" and itemPath="search.loc" limit 1';
        $URL = $this->makeYQL($query);
        if( $this->params->get('useCache')==='1' )
        {
            $data = $this->Cache(
                'location.json',
                array($this,'getCurl'),
                array($URL),
                (60*60*60),
                array($this,'onLocationError')
                );
        } else {
            $data = $this->getCurl($URL);
        }
        $data = json_decode($data,true);
        $this->location = $data['query']['results']['loc']['id'];
    }


    /**
    * Get Weather data
    * 
    */
    private function _getWeatherData()
    {


        $query = 'select * from xml where url="http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w='.$this->woeid.'&u='.$this->params->get('tempUnit').'"';

        $URL = $this->makeYQL($query);
        if( $this->params->get('useCache')==='1' )
        {
            $data = $this->Cache(
                'weather.json',
                array($this,'getCurl'),
                array($URL),
                (int) $this->params->get('cacheTime'),
                array($this,'onDataError')
                );
        } else {
            $data = $this->getCurl($URL);
        }

        return json_decode($data,true);
    }

    /**
    * Get Weather data
    * 
    */
    private function _getForecastData()
    {


        $data = $this->_getWeatherData();

        $location = explode('_',$data['query']['results']['rss']['channel']['item']['guid']['content']);
        $this->location =  $location[0];
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM rss WHERE url="http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/forecastrss/'.$this->location.'&d='.$this->params->get('forecast').'_'.strtolower($this->params->get('tempUnit')).'.xml"';
        $URL = $this->makeYQL($query);

        if( $this->params->get('useCache')==='1' )
        {
            $data = $this->Cache(
                'forecast.json',
                array($this,'getCurl'),
                array($URL),
                (int) $this->params->get('cacheTime'),
                array($this,'onForecastError')
                );

        } else {
            $data = $this->getCurl($URL);
        }
        $data = json_decode($data,true);
        return $data['query']['results']['item']['forecast'];
    }


    /**
    * Convert numeric number to language
    * 
    * @param int | string $number
    * @return language formatted text
    */
    public function Numeric2Lang($number, $prefix = 'SP_')
    {
        $number = (array) str_split($number);
        $formated = '';
        foreach($number as $no)
        {
            if (ctype_digit($no)) {
                $formated.=JText::_($prefix . $no);    
            } else $formated.=$no;


        }
        return $formated;
    }


    /**
    * Weather condition text converter
    * 
    * @param string $text
    * @return string
    */
    public function txt2lng($text)
    {
        $trans = array(" " => "_", "/" => "_", "(" => "", ')'=>'');
        //return $text;
        $text = strtr($text, $trans);
        return JText::_('SP_WEATHER_'.strtoupper($text));
    }

    /**
    * Convert temparature
    * 
    * @param mixed $value
    * @param mixed $unit
    * @param mixed $tempType
    */

    public function convertUnit($value, $unit)
    {    
        $txt  = $this->Numeric2Lang($value);
        $txt .= ( strtolower($unit)=='c') ? JText::_('SP_WEATHER_'. 'C') : JText::_('SP_WEATHER_'. 'F');
        return $txt;
    }    

    /**
    * weather condition to icon file name
    * 
    * @param mixed $icon
    * @param mixed $path
    */
    public function icon($condition)
    {
        $condition = (int) $condition;
        $at = in_array($condition, $this->nightIDs, true)?'n':'d';
        $icon =  sprintf($this->iconURL,$condition,$at);
        return  $icon;
    } 

    /**
    * weather condition to icon font
    * 
    * @param mixed $icon
    * @param mixed $path
    */
    public function iconFont($condition) {

        $night      = in_array($condition, $this->nightIDs, true)?'-night':'';

        $fontIcon   = array(
            "0"     => 'other',
            "1"     => 'storm',
            "2"     => 'storm',
            "3"     => 'chance-of-storm',
            "4"     => 'thunderstorm',          
            "5"     => 'rain-and-snow',
            "6"     => 'sleet',
            "7"     => 'sleet',     
            "8"     => 'rain',    
            "9"     => 'rain',     
            "10"    => 'rain',
            "11"    => 'rain',
            "12"    => 'rain',
            "13"    => 'chance-of-snow',                               
            "14"    => 'snow',
            "15"    => 'snow',
            "16"    => 'snow',
            "17"    => 'chance-of-storm',  
            "18"    => 'rain',
            "19"    => 'dusty',
            "20"    => 'foggy',
            "21"    => 'hazy',
            "22"    => 'smoke',
            "23"    => 'cloudy',
            "24"    => 'cloudy',      
            "25"    => 'snow',
            "26"    => 'cloudy',
            "27"    => 'mostly-cloudy',
            "28"    => 'mostly-cloudy',
            "29"    => 'partly-cloudy',
            "30"    => 'partly-cloudy',
            "31"    => 'sunny',
            "32"    => 'sunny',
            "33"    => 'sunny',
            "34"    => 'partly-cloudy',
            "35"    => 'thunderstorm',
            "36"    => 'sunny',
            "37"    => 'thunderstorm',
            "38"    => 'chance-of-storm',
            "39"    => 'chance-of-storm',
            "40"    => 'rain',
            "41"    => 'snow',
            "42"    => 'snow',
            "43"    => 'snow',
            "44"    => 'partly-cloudy',
            "45"    => 'chance-of-storm',
            "46"    => 'chance-of-snow',
            "47"    => 'chance-of-storm',
            "3200"  => 'other'
            );

            return $fontIcon[$condition] . $night;

    }

    /**
    * Run function to load data from source
    * @return string
    */
    public function getData()
    {
        return $this->data;
    }

    /**
    * Run function to load data from source
    * @return string
    */
    public function getForecastData()
    {
        return $this->forecast;
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

Thanks a lot since now!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quickly looking at the code, I'll explain how it works.

The generic URL for the icons is a string, which is set as a class variable at the top of the file:

```
private $iconURL = 'http://l.yimg.com/os/mit/media/m/weather/images/icons/l/%d%s-100567.png';
```

The string contains 2 variables (`%d` and `%s`) that are changed based on the weather.

- `%d`: is the condition, such as "storm", "foggy", "cloudy" etc.
- `%s`: is the time of day. `n` for night, or `d` for day

Once generated, it will call the image from the URL, like so:

http://l.yimg.com/os/mit/media/m/weather/images/icons/l/0n-100567.png

If you'd like to change the weather icons, I'd suggest changing the class variable `$iconURL` at the top of the file so it's:

http://example.com/images/weathericons/0n-icon.png

Then, you need to make sure you name all your icons like so:

```
0d-icon
0n-icon
1d-icon
1n-icon
2d-icon
2n-icon
etc
```

Go to line 429 of your helper.php, where you'll see an array of all the icons

Comment: Thank you Lodder! It works like a charm!
As because there are 2 kinds of icon (day + night) do you know if I can make the module works only with day icon?
There is no possible to set it form the module panel so I think this is inside a file...

Comment: @Filippo - Glad it helped. If it answered your question, please mark the answer as solved by clicking the tick icon. In regards to the icons...yes you can. You can simply duplicate the day icons (e.g `2d-icon`) and call it `2n-icon`, so the day and night are the same image. Either than or it will require some code changes

Comment: Thanks a lot!
About day/night I thought there was a way to do it without duplicate icons, so in case I want to show  the nights icons I could switch on or off...
Anyway...
Where can I mark solved the post?

Comment: @Filippo - You should see a "tick" icon to the left my main answer